# UITableViewCell not resizing with UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have used parse to store user comments and am displaying these in a UITableViewController. I am trying to make the UITableViewCell dynamic so the cell changes with the size of the UILabel.  I am getting strange results.

My commentTableViewController.m

```
    #import "CommentsTableViewController.h"

#import <Parse/Parse.h>

#import "AddCommentViewController.h"

#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"



@interface CommentsTableViewController ()



@property (strong, nonatomic) CustomTableViewCell *customCell;



@end

@implementation CommentsTableViewController



-(void)viewDidLoad

{

    [self getWallImages];

}



-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

{

    [self getWallImages];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}



-(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated

{

    [self getWallImages];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    return self.commentsArray.count;

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];



    PFObject *commentObject = [self.commentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.userLabel.text = [commentObject objectForKey:@"user"];

    cell.commentLabel.text = [commentObject objectForKey:@"comment”];



        return cell;

}



- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    return self.titleNameString;

}



-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

     if(!self.customCell) {

    self.customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

    }

    PFObject *commentObject = [self.commentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    self.customCell.userLabel.text = [commentObject objectForKey:@"user"];

    self.customCell.commentLabel.text = [commentObject objectForKey:@"comment"];



    self.customCell.commentLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.tableView.bounds.size.width;



    [self.customCell layoutIfNeeded];





    CGFloat height = [self.customCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;



    return height;

 }

-(void)getWallImages

{

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.titleNameString]];

    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {



        if (!error) {



            self.commentsArray = nil;



            self.commentsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];



            [self.tableView reloadData];



        } else {



            NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];



            UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];



            [errorAlertView show];

        }

    }];

}
```

Not sure if it is something to do with settings for my UITableViewCell in the story board or maybe my UILabel constraints....

If i set the Priority constraint of the commentLabel to less than 500 (e.g. 250) I get this (the label overlays all of the cells and generally does not work)

[image: screen cap UITableView]

If the priority is greater than 500 then nothing displays in the cells.

[image: constraints screen cap]

Comment: Can you show the autolayout code as well?

Comment: Where can I find that? I've only ever used it in storyboard

Comment: Maybe you can make a screenshot of the constraints in your storyboard?

Comment: Added screen cap of constraints

Answer (score 1):

Well , I had a similar requirement and the way I built it was that I set the labels constraints to all its edges to the superview i.e. the contentView but did not specify a width or height constraint.

Then I just calculated the height required by the cell for a given text and set the heightForRowAtIndexPath to that calculated height.

So when the cell expands it also pulls the label to fit its height.

Here's a snippet of the function to calculate its height.

```
   -(CGSize)heightforCellForText:(NSString*)text font:(UIFont*)font width:(CGFloat)width
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    label.font = font;
    label.text = text;
    [label sizeToFit];
    return label.frame.size;
}
```

I made this method a little more dynamic to adapt changes in font. So just pass your labels font as a parameter.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //CALCULATE HEIGHT HERE

}
```

This is one of the delegate methods and should fix up the problem. You could calculate the height by seeing how many characters are in the UILabel.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //get the cell
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//say we know that there are 15 characters  per line

int chars = cell.commentLabel.text.length;
int lines = chars/15;

//say our default cell height is 50, maybe we want 5 pts per line

float height = 50 +5*lines;

return height;





}
```

Comment: I have got heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method already, but it doesn't seem to work. Could you look at my code for this method and see where i am going wrong?

Comment: okay the first thing to try is just comment out all the code in that method and set a height manually e.g. 200 and see if it changes the cell height or not. then we can be sure if it's the calculation or not that's causing the problem

Comment: So what I would do then is just write some code to calculate the number of lines in the textfield and produce a height from that. I'll write an example..

Comment: check out what I wrote, it's not code perfect but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Yea i get what you are doing here, it doesn't like CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; for some reason, it keeps crashing when it hits it

Comment: try CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];